# Sorting a Date Column in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, null

I have a table (`master`) with the following columns:

- `Order #` (integer)
- `Location` (varchar)
- `Est Start Date` (date)

I want to return all rows. I want the rows sorted by `Est Start Date`, in ascending order, with rows with a NULL start date showing up at the end of the list.

In addition, I want to include the `Order #` for rows where the `Est Start Date` is not NULL. Where the date is NULL, the `Order #` should be left blank.

The following query is almost working:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [Est Start Date] IS NOT NULL THEN [ORDER #] END,
       [Est Start Date]
  FROM MASTER
 ORDER BY [Est Start Date] ASC;
```

The only problem is that the rows with a NULL `Est Start Date` are showing up first, instead of last.

Here an example of what the output should look like:

```
Order# | LOCATION | Est Start Date
-------+----------+-----------------
1      | Test 1   | 7/18/2017
2      | Test 2   | 8/10/2017
3      | Test 3   | 9/1/2017
4      | Test 4   | 9/18/2017
5      | Test 5   | 10/3/2017
6      | Test 6   | 10/13/2017
7      | Test 7   | 10/22/2017
8      | Test 8   | 11/1/2017
9      | Test 9   | 11/12/2017
10     | Test 10  | 12/3/2017
11     | Test 11  | 12/6/2017
12     | Test 12  | 1/24/2018
13     | Test 13  | 2/6/2018
14     | Test 14  | 2/26/2018
15     | Test 15  | 3/17/2018
16     | Test 16  | 4/9/2018
17     | Test 17  | 4/27/2018
       | Test 18  | 5/17/2018
       | Test 19  | NULL
       | Test 20  | NULL
       | Test 21  | NULL
       | Test 22  | NULL
       | Test 23  | NULL
```

How can I get them to show up last?

Answer (score 4):

So, what you want is to:

- list all records
- do not show the `Order #` if the `Est Start Date` is NULL (it's not clear whether these rows can have an `Order #` or not; your sample code seems to allow for them to have one that shouldn't be shown)
- sort all rows with a NULL `Est Start Date` to the end of the result set (as if they had a later date than everything else)

Your sample query already has the `Order #` showing as NULL if the `Est Start Date` is NULL; all that seems left to do is to force rows with a NULL `Est Start Date` to sort as a later date than everything else.

I've done this in the past by replacing my actual field in the `ORDER BY` clause with a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [Est Start Date] IS NOT NULL THEN [ORDER #] END,
       [Est Start Date]
  FROM MASTER
 ORDER BY
       CASE WHEN [Est Start Date] IS NULL
         THEN '9999-12-31'
         ELSE [Est Start Date]
       END ASC;
```

This won't change the displayed data, but will force rows with NULL dates to show up at the end of the listing.

NOTE: [Colin 't Hart](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/10361/colin-t-hart) pointed to a [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456653/sql-server-equivalent-to-oracles-nulls-first) that covers a number of similar options, the simplest and most flexible of which is:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [Est Start Date] IS NOT NULL THEN [ORDER #] END,
       [Est Start Date]
  FROM MASTER
 ORDER BY
       CASE WHEN [Est Start Date] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC,
       [Est Start Date] ASC;
```

This works with any datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this,

```
SELECT CASE WHEN sdate IS NOT NULL THEN ordernum END,
  location,
  sdate
FROM tbl
ORDER BY sdate DESC;
```